# How to set PYTHONHASHSEED in AWS Lambda

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to use `hash()` to get consistent values from reoccuring data. Is there a way to set `PYTHONHASHSEED=0` so that I won't have to use a different approach? I suppose hashlib would work, but that's a bit of an overkill here.

Comment: @kdgregory Does this work for you when done in Python code? I get non-determinate results and need to set it via the calling shell script in order for it to have an effect.

Comment: @JackKinsella - tbh, I never tried it. But it makes sense that it would be something that's consumed by the Python runtime before it ever gets to your code. I'll delete the comment.